# Select quantity on a 1st table based on a total quantity the 2nd table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1

| ID | Grp | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 2 | A | 4 |
| 3 | B | 5 |
| 4 | B | 3 |
| 5 | B | 2 |
| 6 | C | 14 |
| 7 | D | 1 |
| 8 | D | 1 |
| 9 | E | 2 |
| 10 | E | 2 |
| 11 | E | 1 |
| 12 | E | 1 |

Table 2

| ID | Grp | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 7 |
| 2 | B | 9 |
| 3 | C | 13 |
| 4 | D | 1 |
| 5 | E | 4 |

Select/Output

| ID | Grp | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 2 | A | 2 |
| 3 | B | 0 |
| 4 | B | 0 |
| 5 | B | 1 |
| 6 | C | 1 |
| 7 | D | 0 |
| 8 | D | 1 |
| 9 | E | 0 |
| 10 | E | 0 |
| 11 | E | 1 |
| 12 | E | 1 |

I want to select a row on a 1st table with a specific quantity based on the total quantity of the 2nd table. The result is on the 3rd table. Please see sample tables above, I really appreciate a help, thank you so much and sorry it was my first time asking a question here.

I have tried this code on both 2 tables

```
WITH tbl AS(
SELECT ID, 
       Qty, 
       Grp, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp)AS Rown,
       SUM(Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp)AS Total
FROM Table1  
)
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Rown = 1
```

But I am not able to select the specific rows on Table 1 because it only select the 1st row and total the quantity. Every row on table 1 has its own quantity.

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you please enter your sample output?

Comment: My sample output is on the 3rd table

Comment: So what are you expected results is the table called `Select` is your sample data. are `Table 1` and `Table 2` actually your expected results then? `Table 2` just looks like a `SUM` of `Select` apart from where `Group` has a have of `C`; I don't know how you get `13` from a single `9`.

Comment: When you posted your question you were asked to *"Explain how you encountered the problem you’re trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself."* You haven't done this.

Comment: You were also asked *"Show what you’ve tried, tell us what happened, and why it didn’t meet your needs. Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."* This is all missing too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"I have tried several ways such as doing case and row_number."* You need to include those attempts.

Comment: I edited my questions based on your suggestions above, I am very sorry it was my 1st time posting a question. Hope you'll help me thank you so much

Comment: @Larnu It sounds like table1 is orders and table2 is stock so the result is available stock for each order.

Comment: @Kendle, It is a comparison of the total quantity of 2 tables and the excess must be denied. Table 1 is dependent on the total quantity of table 2. Example if theres a 3 quantity on table 2 then table 1 must only have 3 quantity also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cumulative windowed aggregates and then a `CASE` expression to achieve this:

```sql
--Saple Data
WITH Table1 AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'A',5),
                (2,'A',4),
                (3,'B',5),
                (4,'B',3),
                (5,'B',2),
                (6,'C',14))V(ID,Grp,Qty)),
Table2 AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'A',7),
                (2,'B',9),
                (3,'C',13))V(ID,Grp,Qty)),
--Solution
CTE AS(
    SELECT T1.ID,
           T1.Grp,
           T1.Qty,
           SUM(T1.Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Grp ORDER BY T1.Id
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningQty,
           T2.Qty AS T2Qty
    FROM Table1 T1
         JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Grp = T2.Grp)
SELECT C.ID,
       C.Grp,
       CASE WHEN C.RunningQty <= C.T2Qty THEN C.Qty
            ELSE C.T2Qty - LAG(C.RunningQty,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY C.Grp ORDER BY C.ID)
       END AS Qty
FROM CTE C;
```

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me. From your comment I tried selecting the opposite which I only select those excess quantity from the 1st table but I cant, I thought the code can be done vice versa. I also update the table from my question. 
This is the only code that I changed: 
ELSE LAG(C.RunningQty,0,1) OVER (PARTITION BY C.Grp ORDER BY C.ID) - C.T2Qty

Comment: @Jayson if you have a new question, then post a new question, don't change the goalposts after you've had answers.

Comment: I will and I really appreciate your answer it did helped me. Thank you so much.